# Can't build docker container in subfolder

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following directory structure

all_services

- service A

  - Dockerfile
  - requirements.txt
- service B
- ...

My Dockerfile consists of among other things

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

...

# copy all requirements
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

...
```

Unfortunately, docker responds with the following error message.

```
Step 7/15 : COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder876603503/requirements.txt: no such file or directory
```

It is a mystery to me as the requirements.txt file is in the same directory as the Dockerfile. Copying these 2 files up in the hierarchy below all_services, i.e.,

all_services

- Dockerfile
- requirements.txt
- service A
- service B
- ...

and I have no problems, but clearly that is not how I want to organize my files. I removed caches etc to be sure, but to no avail. I tried on a different machine with the same folder structure and files -> same problem, so it does not seem to be machine / docker installation specific.
Any ideas?

Comment: How do you build the image and from which directory do you execute the build command?

Answer (score 0):

stupid error. I completely missed that due to a copy-paste error, I had a *.txt in my .dockerignore which is in the service A folder, but not in the main folder.

Case closed.